# android gridview scrolling image misplace

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I'm having problem with gridview. I'm using a very simple GridView where I have image and a textView below that.
My problem is - I'm showing 3 images per row and 12 images are shown at a time on my screen but for 13th image the image is correct but the text below that is of 1st image.
If I'm using 4 images per row(that I dont want to do) then the text shown is correct.
also after scrolling the images and text of gridview interchanges

Here is my custom gridview.java code

```
public class CustomGrid extends BaseAdapter{
  private Context mContext;
  private final String[] web;
  private final int[] Imageid; 

    public CustomGrid(Context c,String[] web,int[] Imageid ) {
        mContext = c;
        this.Imageid = Imageid;
        this.web = web;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return web.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View grid;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {  

            grid = new View(mContext);
            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single, null);
            TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
            textView.setText(web[position]);
            imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[position]);
        } else {
            grid = (View) convertView;
        }

        return grid;
    }
}
```

please reply as soon as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably you need to change the code as following.For the 13th item convert view is not null so its returning old 1st view.

> @Override
>       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
>           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>           View grid;
>           LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
>
> ```
>     if (convertView == null) {  
>
>         grid = new View(mContext);
>         grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single, null);
>         TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
>         ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
>
>     } else {
>         grid = (View) convertView;
>     }
>         textView.setText(web[position]);
>         imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[position]);
>     return grid;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         View grid; 
         LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (convertView == null) {  

                grid = new View(mContext);
                grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single, null);

            } else {
                grid = (View) convertView;
            }
            TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
             ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
                textView.setText(web[position]);
                imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[position]);
            return grid;
    }
```